# Weird django character input

Tags: django

Just open django admin and edit a CharField. Copy this character `ﺣ` and then type a number. The number moves to the beginning during typing.

What the heck is happenning there?

Comment: Just as a prewarning to anyone else, don't just do a google search for that character alone, its NSFW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That character is from [modern arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) and arabic is one of the languages written [right to left](http://www.i18nguy.com/temp/rtl.html), hence it makes sense that after writing this character you'll want to write the next one to the left of it.

This has nothing to do with django, it is just modern browser support for right to left written languages.